# Break from the inner nested stream when no elements are passed through filter

Tags: java, java-stream

Here is the example of code that I struggle with:

```
List<CategoryHolder> categories = ...
List<String> categoryNames = categoryIds.stream()
                    .map(id -> categories.stream()
                            .filter(category -> category.getId().equals(id))
                            .findFirst().get().getName())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So I have a list of `CategoryHolder` objects consisting of `category.id` and `category.name`. I also have a list of category ids. I want to iterate through ids and for each id I want to iterate through the `CategoryHolder` list and when `id` from `categoryIds` list is matched with a `CategoryHolder.id` I want to return the `category.name`. So basically I want to map every value from `categoryIds` to its `category.name`.

So the problem is when no values are matched, filter doesn't pass any elements through and there is nothing to collect, so I would like to break from the current inner stream, and continue to the next id from `categoryIds` list. Is there a way to achieve this in stream API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
categories.stream()
            .filter(categoryHolder -> categoryIds.stream()
                          .anyMatch(id->categoryHolder.getId().equals(id)))
            .map(CategoryHolder::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or for better performance you can do:

```
Map<String,CategoryHolder> map = categories.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(CategoryHolder::getId, Function.identity()));

List<String> names = categoryIds.stream()
            .map(id -> map.get(id).getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your call to filter where you are doing `.findFirst().get().getName()`

This would fail in case empty Optional is returned by `findFirst()`.

You can instead rewrite it as follows:

```
List<String> categoryNames = 
          categoryIds
           .stream()
           .map(id -> categories
                       .stream()
                       .filter(catgory -> catgory.getId().equals(id))
                       .findFirst())
           .collect(
               ArrayList::new, 
               (list, optional) -> {
                    optional.ifPresent(categoryHolder -> list.add(categoryHolder.name));
                }, 
              (list, list2) -> {}
            );
```